# How does a choice of linearisation of a line bundle fix a moment map?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, symplectic-geometry, kahler-manifolds, line-bundles

Let $G \times M \to M$ be a weak Hamiltonian action of a Lie group on a Kahler manifold. Suppose we fix a lift/linearisation of the action of $G$ to an ample line bundle $L \to M$.

Apparently this fixes a canonical choice of moment map. Can someone explain this to me?

I don't know whether this is correct, but we have an embedding in $\mathbb{P}^N$ given by $L$. Does the linearisation induce an action on $\mathbb{P}^N$, where we do have a canonical choice of moment map?

Comment: Could you please expand on the definitions and the hypotheses you're working with? For instance, several authors define a *Hamiltonian action* to be one such that the infinitesimal action is explicitly induced by a map $h: \mathfrak{g} \to C^{\infty}(M)$ (whose transpose determines **the** moment map), calling instead *weak Hamiltonian* an action for which a choice of $h$ can be made but wasn't made beforehand. In any case, whenever $M$ is compact, there is a standard choice of $h$ for any (weak) Hamiltonian action, namely choose each $h(X)$ to have zero mean over $M$.

Comment: You mention the tag "kahler-manifolds", but nowhere in your question it's mentioned that $M$ is Kahler. This would be necessary in order to be able to make sense of the 'holomorphic sections' of the (ample) line bundle $L$ (for **compact** $M$), as these are the ones which would embed $M$ into some $\mathbb{C}P^N$. (It is an important work of Donaldson to show how one could generalize the embedding to any compact symplectic manifold, but it wouldn't be quite canonical as it depends on auxiliary choices...) And *if* an action was induced on $\mathbb{C}P^N$ why would its moment map be canonical?

Comment: Thanks. I should try and give more context.

Comment: @JordanPayette I'm basically trying my best to understand what choice of moment map is present here - https://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.8264.pdf

Comment: see for example 1.2. I think I've figured out what they're doing. I may update later

Answer (score 1):

Check the notes of Victoria Hoskins "SYMPLECTIC QUOTIENTS: MOMENT MAPS, SYMPLECTIC
REDUCTION AND THE MARSDEN-WEINSTEIN-MEYER THEOREM"